# GCM life cycle confusion and wanting to always be registered

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have GCM completely working. My question is when I exit my app with the android BACK key I see the onDestroy() called and to avoid leaks I unregistered the receiver for gcm so it's onUnregister() is called. But I want to be able to register gcm once at power up (boot completed?) and then be able to get notifications any time. I know I will need to still handle when google may refresh the reg intent.  But I'm not clear if I need to make a new service to register gcm in in its onCreate()?  Right now I register gcm in the main activity's onCreate().

Thanks for any help!!

Justin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without looking at your code it's a bit hard to tell, but you should not be unregistering from GCM every time you leave the app. A typical GCM App life-cycle (if you are using the GCM jar) would be the following:

1. App starts and checks to see if it has a GCM registrationID (which means that it registered with GCM) then checks to see if it has registered with your server.
2. If it has a registrationID but has not registered with your server it attempts to do that.
3. If it does not have a registrationID it attempts to register with GCM, and then when it gets the registrationID it will attempt to register with your server

Number 4 would probably be unregistered from GCM when they turned off a preference to unregister from receiving notifications.

Take a look at Google's Client sample DemoActivity: http://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/samples/gcm-demo-client/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/app/DemoActivity.java

Notice that they do not unregistered from GCM. If you follow their sample you will receive notifications after the device powers up without having to do anything else yourself.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I started reviewing the demo client code again.  I'll work on updating my code to use GCMRegistrar().  I had done it all I think before that was available?  So based on that code, if your app is totally destroyed and then onCreate() is called again, calling the function GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId() will hopefully tell you if it's been too long and GCM doesn't know about your phone's registration anymore.

Comment: So I refactored my app to use GCMRegistrar quickly, and it complained 1 time about leaking of a GCM broadcast receiver on my first exit.  But then after that it never complained again.  And it definitely stayed registered.  So I guess it's all good, but I still need to play around a bit to make sure I'm not missing something.  I saw this other thread on here ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299312/leaked-intentreceiver-in-google-cloud-messaging ) and so I added GCMRegistrar.onDestroy() call from my main activity's onDestroy() and it still didn't call unregister.

Comment: Yes, that is the way to do it. If you get a blank Registration ID then ti's time to register with GCM again. The same goes for determining if you are still registered on your server. As far as the leak I believe I switched to using the Application Context to avoid that.

Comment: The warning what you get about leaking of a broadcast receiver on the exit is because your activity is been registered to receive a broadcast (it is the broadcast and NOT the GCM message!) once the activity is destroyed it will no more be able to receive the broad cast so it's correct to un-register from the broadcast. It is the service's duty to receive messages from the GCM server as it exists and running even after the application exit. After receiving the message it shows the notification and sends the broad cast (if the activity is running will receive the broadcast and do something).

Comment: Good point, if you are using a Broadcast receiver to communicate between the GCM service and your activity then you need to unregister that before your activity is destroyed. Hopefully I didn't add to the confusion, thanks for commenting.