# Should we unregister the receiver in gcm (Android)

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, server-push

I got `deviceId` from GCM upon successful registration. I am storing my `deviceId` in `SharedPreferences`. In the main activity I am unregistering the receiver in `onDestroy()` method.
If I don't unregister the reciever then I am getting memory leak errors.
Will these errors effect the application?.
If so then when should i unregister the receiver?
I dont have logout button in my application.

I even have doubt that if we unregister the receiver shall we able to receive the push notifications?

Please help me out. I am totally confused.

Answer (score 2):

I think that there is misunderstanding between an unregistration from GCM services and unregistration of a broadcastereceiver declared in an activity.

The kind of error you posted:

> MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver MainActivity$1@416321f0 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()

Looks like when you use a broadcastreceiver to receive the `Intents` from the GCMIntentService when you get a message at `onMessage()`.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver myBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   ....
   }
}
```

In this case,yes you have to call `unregisterReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver)` to a void the memory leak error.

This action is not going to cancel the push notifications it's only going to stop the boadcastreceiver to listen those intents. GCMIntentService will still receive messages.

Comment: Exactly. I use a broadcast receiver to receive the intents from the GCMIntentService when I get a message at onMessage().Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you unregister from the GCM service, you will no longer receive push notifications.

Comment: but if i don't unregister then i am getting memory leakage errors.Will these errors effect my application.

Comment: you will have to elaborate what "memory leakage errors" you are talking about.  are you seeing this in logcat?  if so, would you post it?

Comment: MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver MainActivity$1@416321f0 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?

Comment: looks like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278464/leaked-intentreceiver-error-when-calling-gcmregistrar-register

Comment: summary: make sure you're calling GCMRegistrar.onDestroy() from your onDestroy() handler.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26999/discussion-between-user1659390-and-j-m)

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not want to unregister. It will un-register itself once you uninstall the app (eventually). Until then you just want to keep it on so you can receive notifications.